# ImageMenuItem Icons in Python AppIndicator

Tags: indicator

I tried to create an AppIndicator using gtk.ImageMenuItems. Normally ImageMenuItems display the stock's item, but using Python AppIndicator no Icons in the menu are displayed at all. Is this a lacking feature ?

Here is my example code. Of course the indicator displays an icon but non of the menu entries:

```
exit_item = gtk.ImageMenuItem(stock_id=gtk.STOCK_QUIT)
exit_item.connect("activate", quit, None)
exit_item.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default icons on menu entries are not displayed (you can change that somewhere in GConf/DConf). Use

```
exit_item.set_always_show_image(True)
```

to override this.

Comment: Thank you Florian. I didn't know that this was disabled by default. This works fine.